# Laravel: CSRF token mismatch with X-XSRF-TOKEN

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-8

Is there a way to make it work an ajax request with header `X-XSRF-TOKEN`?

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    headers: { 'X-XSRF-TOKEN': token },
    url: '/edit_preset_filters',
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
        $('#errorSaveFilter').hide();
        $('#save-filters').dialog('close');

    }
});
```

Error message

> message   "CSRF token mismatch."
> exception   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException"

This way I get the token

```php
<?php
$encrypter = app('Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter');
$encrypted_token = $encrypter->encrypt(csrf_token());
```

```html
<input id="token" type="hidden" value="{{$encrypted_token}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to add additional lines for csrf token just add this line,

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

And in ajax call

```
var token =  $('input[name="token"]').val();
```